# Create User in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

Is it possible to create an user without create user command? I mean just by make an entry(framing insert query) in mysql.user table? Will it cause any crash in system tables?

Comment: *make an entry(framing insert query) in mysql.user table* Create record in mysql.user is not enough. *Will it cause any crash in system tables?* Hardly... but the account will be unusable.

Comment: You can create a user indirectly by doing a `GRANT ... ON table.* TO 'user'@''hostname/ip'  IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '...';` which will both grant and add the entry is mysql.user

Comment: Why do you feel the desire / need to do this?  What /problem/ are you trying to solve?  Clearly, you are already concerned about this approach, because you're asking the question ...

Comment: I used skip-grant-tables to start the mysql(I forgot the password ). I could not create any users while using skip-grant-table. Is it possible by inserting directly into the system table in this case?